# About float in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How to float icon on the left and text on the right?

Sorry I cant post images. You can see on `http://i.upanh.com/vafsnn`

```
div class="col-md-3 ">
                <img src="img/service1.png"/>
                <div class="column4">
                    <h1>New way of vision</h1>
                    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, telssa jumalesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
                 </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: add `.pull-left` and `.pull-right` class.

Comment: javascript. did you try searching for ways of animating html elements? this is a very basic question, there is plenty of resources and similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap already has two class named `.pull-left` and `.pull-right`.

So add them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

.pull-left  for floating left and .pull-right for floating right

Comment: i try to put .pull-right and .pull-left class, but nothing happen. please edit on Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vmars/h7KtU/

Answer (score 0):

Add `pull-right` and `pull-left` for floating element in bootstrap.

```
<div class="col-md-3 ">
                <img src="img/service1.png" class='pull-left'/>
                <div class="column4" class='pull-right'>
                    <h1>New way of vision</h1>
                    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, telssa jumalesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
                 </div>
 </div>
```

**Updates:** From you JSFiddle,

1) You haven't included the **bootstrap.css**

check the [**updated JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h7KtU/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-md-3 ">
    <img style="float:left" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/"/>
    <div class="column4">
        <h1>New way of vision</h1>
        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, telssa jumalesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gGxm7/

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS: See full jsFiddle here:http://jsfiddle.net/AuLtx/

```
 .image-css{
  height:45px;
  width:45px;
  float:left;
 }

 .column4 { margin-left:100px; margin-top:0px; margin-right:0px;}
```